# What is the meaing of yield on tokio async rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

When reading Tokio rust documentation, it talks about yielding control back to the thread. Does this means that the function ended his execution and has returned a value?

The exact quote from tokio.rs is:

> The async fn definition looks like a regular synchronous function, but operates asynchronously. Rust transforms the async fn at compile time into a routine that operates asynchronously. Any calls to .await within the async fn yield control back to the thread. The thread may do other work while the operation processes in the background.

Comment: No, this means that the function indicated that it is waiting for IO, and the task scheduler can now reuse the same thread to run some other task.

Comment: @IvanC and how can the task scheduler now when to try again? It just tries and if it fails continues with something else or is more complicated than that?

Comment: The simplest possible executor would be a busy loop repeatedly polling the future, yes. Something like `tokio` is a lot more complicated though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has not ended, just paused. It will continue when the future will be polled again.

Here's an example:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

async fn bar() {
    // Force to yield back to the caller.
    let mut yielded = false;
    std::future::poll_fn(move |_| {
        if !yielded {
            yielded = true;
            Poll::Pending
        } else {
            Poll::Ready(())
        }
    })
    .await;
}

async fn foo() {
    println!("before");
    bar().await;
    println!("after");
}

fn main() {
    let waker = futures::task::noop_waker();
    let mut context = Context::from_waker(&waker);

    let mut future = Box::pin(foo());
    // First, poll the future once.
    assert_eq!(future.as_mut().poll(&mut context), Poll::Pending);
    // Now the future is paused at the `.await` inside `bar()`. Poll it again so it completes.
    assert_eq!(future.as_mut().poll(&mut context), Poll::Ready(()));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b5496fb6539a477f63f5989e7effca4).

Usually, the [`Waker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/task/struct.Waker.html) registers to future to be polled again when some event happens, and then the scheduler poll it when the even happens. For example, if you do I/O in tokio, the waker given to your future will register it to be polled again when the I/O is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of tokio (and other async runtimes) as schedulers and async functions as tasks to be completed. In this context, 'yeild' means a running task can decide to **pause** execution to give control back to the scheduler so the thread can be used to work on another task (if there are other tasks queued). If there are no other tasks available, then the scheduler may decide to continue the previous task. The task does not end. It is more like we save our place within the task so we can go back to it later.

So when you call an async function, you are essentially giving a new task to the scheduler. Then when you use `.await` you are telling the scheduler that you want to wait for the result of that task. This makes yielding desirable since there is nothing we can do until the other task is completed and we want to free up resources so that other tasks can be worked on while we wait.

Comment: And how does the scheduler can know when he can continue with a task? It might be crate dependent this so in case of tokio how does this work?

Comment: @ParawaPa  There are no restrictions on when the scheduler can continue execution of a task that has yielded. That being said, when we call an async function it returns a [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html). You can think of this as a handle for the task that was just created. Unlike when we call [`yield_now()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.24.2/tokio/task/fn.yield_now.html), awaiting a `Future` means the scheduler can use the `poll` method of that `Future` to determine when it has reached completed and execution can be resumed.

Comment: @ParawaPa the [`poll()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) method on `Future`s are given a "context" which you can use to notify the scheduler that the task may be able to make progress.